# How do I solve dependencies with replacements?

Tags: xorg, dependencies, packaging

I work on a solution getting a closed-source driver, called EMGD, working on Ubuntu.
But there is a problem with the lubuntu-desktop package.
It depends on lubuntu-core -> xorg and xorg needs xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+7ubuntu2).
I need an older version xserver-xorg to get the driver working. So I made a package called xserver-xorg-1.9, which provides xserver-xorg and got a higher version than 1:7.7+7ubuntu2.

Why does it still conflict? I really do not get what apt still misses..

- debian/control: https://github.com/EMGD-Community/xserver-xorg/blob/master/debian/control
- recipe: https://code.launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+recipe/xserver-xorg-emgd
- ppa: https://code.launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/emgd

Comment: I am a bit confused. The `xserver-xorg` packages seem to be named just that: `xserver-xorg`, etc., whereas your binary packages seem to have the version in the package name: `xserver-xorg-1.9`. Did I miss something?

Comment: The closed-source driver I alteady packaged needs a downgrade. It needs a specific version of X, here 1.9. Newer versions do not fit to the ABI of the driver. So my package replaces the upstream package and downgrades it on the system.

Comment: Thats ok, but why the version number in the package name?

Comment: Well, I thought it would be easier to identify this downgrade eg. in case someone wants to remove it again. Bad idea?

Comment: i think so, since the package name is the first thing that must match. Only then does the version comparison come into picture. Think of it thus: if the requirement is `blah`, then I have to name it `blah`, anything else `blah-1`, `ahshjdjeindke`, etc are unrelated packages as far as `blah` is concerned.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I just wonderd why it always handles the dependencies like that as I set it provides xserver-xorg (virtual package). Looks like I have to add a meta-pavkage to cserver-xorg or rename it. But will wait for some time maybe someone finds the real reason. But many thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The version, conflicts and dependencies are included in the .deb package, more precisely in `package-root/DEBIAN/control`. Did you adapt these?

DPKG doesn't determine the package version by the name, but by the version specified in the control file.

Comment: Just added now more details above. Sorry for not doing that while asking. I set the version of my package higher than the upstream and set it provides xserver-xorg plus added Conflicts and Breaks to be sure it removes it before unpacking. Did I miss something? :/